# watch with rsync fails with permission denied, while rsync alone just works fine

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, rsync, watch

I'm trying to sync my files to cloud:

```
rsync -avPze "ssh -i /path/to/my/key" [source] [destination]
```

this works successfully for me.

However, when I try to use the same command with `watch` in order to sync automatically every couple minutes, it doesn't work and throws error:

```
watch -n120 rsync -avPze "ssh -i /path/to/my/key" [source] [destination]
```

Error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Does `watch` run under a different user than the one owning the key? You can check with something like: `ps aux | awk '/\<watch\>/ || NR==1'`

Comment: @andlrc, actually yes! `watch` is running as root where as the key owner is a user. However, even `rsync` runs as root and without `watch`, it executes without any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclosing the whole `rsync` command within quotes, does the trick.

```
watch -n120 "rsync -avPze 'ssh -i /path/to/my/key' [source] [destination]"
```

Observed from `strace` output:

```
execve("/usr/bin/watch", ["watch", "-n120", "rsync", "-avPze", "ssh -i '/path/to/my/key'", "source"..., "destination"...], [/* 21 vars */]) = 0
```

While `rsync` has properly initiated with `source` and `destination` being the far end arguments, and path is full path to key. `permission denied` error is misleading.

Comment: do you mind to mark your own answer as resolving? ;)

Comment: @silpol, hey thankyou! I was just waiting if someone has some good explanation for this kind of behaviour :)